# How can I calculate the amount of possible routes someone could take on a grid with a specific size?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I created a simple game, and I want to calculate approximately how many possible moves there are on a board of N x N squares.
The rules are as follows:

- The player starts on the top left corner
- Every turn, the player can move to any horizontally or vertically adjacent square that has not been visited before
- The game ends when the player can no longer move

This might seem difficult, but it's really simple. Here's a two samples [game 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrsG6.gif), [game 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK9Cd.gif)

My question is: How can I calculate the total amount of games on any given grid?

I tried simulating it, but it takes way too long because it grows so quickly. Here is what I have now:

*N - Possible Games

1 - 0

2 - 2

3 - 20

4 - 548

5 - 40440

6 - 8442742*

I left my computer running for almost an hour to calculate 7 but I still didn't have a number, but based on how fast it grows I expect it to be around 4.8 billion. And I expect 8 to be around 7.6 trillion. However, I have no proof of this, I just noticed that if you calculate the percentual differences between the numbers, and then calculate the percentual differences between those, they end up being approximately 2.75
[not a very rigorous proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMpIq.png)

Is there anything I can look into that is related to this? I have no idea where to begin calculating this.

Comment: [OEIS A341269](https://oeis.org/A341269) gives $5088482972$, $8963926817126$, $46591697187961736$ as the next terms (and $1$ for the number on a $0\times 0$ square$)

Comment: @Henry This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: I should have said "(and $1$ for the number on a $1\times 1$ square)"